# Jquery on mouse over

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery,i need to develop a small application,on span mouse over there should be small popup showing related data on it.like tooltip using jquery.
could any one help me out.
Hint: in BookMyshow website,if you mouse over on the time it wil show the ticket availablity on top of the time.in small window

Comment: [Come on, is it really so hard?!](https://www.google.com/?q=jquery%20tooltip)

Answer (score 1):

see my fiddle. i am not using span tag but using a href. http://jsfiddle.net/cfmlprabhu/pcq49jh9/

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" title="This will show up in the tooltip" class="masterTooltip">Your Text</a>
    <p title="Mouse over the heading above to view the tooltip." class="masterTooltip">Mouse over the    heading text above to view it's tooltip.</p>
```

CSS:

```
    .tooltip {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background-color:#161616;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:12px Arial;
   }
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // Tooltip only Text
    $('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
        // Hover over code
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
   }, function() {
        // Hover out code
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
   }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it can be done like this, just change the style and positioning to the ones you like:

Html:

```
<span id="span">My Span</span>
```

Css:

```
#info{
    position:realtive;
    z-index:100;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;  
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#span").on("mouseenter",function(){
        if($("#info").length==0){
            $("body").append('<div id="info">info</div>');
        }
    }).on("mouseleave",function(){
        if($("#info").length){
            $("#info").remove();
        }        
    });
});
```

And the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xhuy16jy/